# UK fee-free foreign transfer to own account

Tags: united-kingdom, fees, international-transfer

I have a bank account in the UK and in The Netherlands.  Transferring money from my UK to my Dutch bank account costs £25 with my current bank and most other banks have similar fees.  The [Money saving expert](http://www.moneysavingexpert.com/banking/foreign-currency-exchange) notes that there exist some fee-free transfers when accounts are with linked banks.  But I also found that both [NS&I](http://www.nsandi.com/international-payments-service) and the [Post Office](http://www.postoffice.co.uk/international-payments) have what appears to be a fee-free international payments service.  That appears to be a major advantage over the competitors, and this is not mentioned by the Money saving expert.  I wonder if I'm missing something.

Is there a catch with the [Post Office](http://www.postoffice.co.uk/international-payments) and [NS&I's free international payments services](http://www.nsandi.com/international-payments-service) that I am missing, or something I am misunderstanding?  No other sites seem to contain these options.

---

**Note:**  This question is different from *[Which UK banks have an account that features free online incoming/outgoing international wire transfers and no monthly charges?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7221)*.  Firstly, I am willing to accept the limitation that both accounts are in the same name.  Secondly, the accepted answer to the linked question is incorrect, because it provides a service that does *not* allow for free outgoing transfers.  Thirdly, I am not interested in receiving money, only sending.  Fourthly, The linked question asks for *no monthly fees*, my question does not.

Comment: Why don't _you_ figure out what the answer to your first question is, and post it here as an answer to your own question so that future visitors will be able to get this nugget of information from money.SE and we will be a little closer to the goal?

Comment: @DilipSarwate I am unsure about posting it as an answer because I find it hard to believe that most banks charge £25 or more, that some banks offer it for free.  I suspect there must be a catch somewhere.